# ld cannot find libjasper library

Tags: c, linker-errors, ld

I am trying to link an application with gc on Ubuntu 18.04. ld cannot find the libjasper library. I installed it manually with these commands:

```
sudo apt update 

sudo apt install libjasper1 libjasper-dev
```

but got this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibjasper
```

I tried this command to add the library but didn't work:

```
gcc -o cnn connected_layer.c connected_layer.h convolutional_layer.c convolutional_layer.h image.c image.h maxpool_layer.c maxpool_layer.h network.c network.h tests.c -Wall `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -flto -ffast-math -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -l libjasper
```

Comment: The name of the library is `jasper`. The `lib` prefix and any possible suffixes are not used in the name.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 -l libjasper
```

by

```
 -l jasper
```

`lib` is just a mandatory suffix to library files, which is ignored when specifying the name to the linker.

Comment: I found two libraries using "locate jasper" in the terminal:

Comment: /usr/include/jasper

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.a

Which one should I use ?

Comment: If everything installed well, just use `-l japser`.

Comment: @I.Bou "Which one should I use". The first is the directory where library's header files are, for use by the compiler. The second is the *library*, for use by the linker. You compile, then link. Both are used.